# Progress bar when doing a tar

Tags: tar, copy

I everyday has to copy files from my computer to an SD card using:

```
tar zxvf file.tar.gz -C /path_to_SD_card
```

Ubuntu execute that command instantly, but as you may know, it keeps copying the files in background. So I need to know when the copy process has concluded.

Is there any way to know that? something like a progress bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't believe a progress bar is possible since that would require it to perform a scan over all of the files first.  I don't think `tar` does that...  `rsync` does do that and if you were to run `rsync`, you will see how many files are left if you used the `--progress` option.

Comment: Use the `sync` command after the `tar` command. On slow SD cards or USB flash disks the `tar` command may take only a few _seconds_, while the `sync` command may take _minutes_. So, the correct usage in your case will be: `tar -xvf file.tar.gz -C /path_to_SD_card ; sync`. And it is not possible to have a "progress bar" in such a case, since it will be impossible to know (in advance) how long the `sync` command will last.

Answer (score 2):

No progress bar here: The delay is not from the *tar* process, but from the kernel I/O subsystem not quite being finished.

*tar* reads that archive file and writes it to the filesystem on your SD card, but that goes into kernel buffers first. The kernel reports to *tar* that the operation is complete, but it still keeps flushing those buffers to the hardware. Worse, most modern SD cards / USB sticks have some hardware buffer, too, that also needs to be flushed.

If you want to script that, you can send a `sync` command after your `tar` command; this will well and truly block everything until all buffers are flushed (written to the actual hardware):

```
tar -xvf myarchive.tgz -C /media/sdcard
sync
```

(Notice that *tar* is smart enough since many years to detect the compression method upon unpacking, so you can omit it for `-x` and `-t`)